# LWC Html table with lightning-input onchange giving error

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, onchange

I have a html table in my LWC child component which is populated from the parent. I am able to pass the values and display the data on the child component. On the child component the table has a number of lightning-input fields.
In the onchange, I am able to get the value from the UI, but when I assign the value as shown in the JS code below, I keep getting this error.

**"This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: -465312255)"**

**Below is my code**

```
<template for:each={configureorderitemlist} for:item="orderItem"  for:index="index">
<tr key={orderItem.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
     <td data-label="Unit Price" scope="row" style="font-size: small;">
         <lightning-input type="text" value={orderItem.UnitPrice} 
           onchange=handleUnitPriceChange} data-index={index}>
         </lightning-input>
     </td>
</tr>
</template>
```

**JS code:**

```
@api configureorderitemlist // passed from parent

handleUnitPriceChange(event)
{
        
this.unitPrice = event.detail.value;

const itemIndex = event.currentTarget.dataset.index;

var rowData = this.configureorderitemlist[itemIndex];

console.log('totalAmount-->',rowData.TotalAmount); // prints the value

console.log('rowData-->', JSON.stringify(rowData));

let totalAmt = this.unitPrice*this.qty;

console.log('totalAmt-->', totalAmt);

rowData.TotalAmount = 100;----------- At this line its throwing error

console.log('rowData.TotalAmount-->', rowData);

this.configureorderitemlist[itemIndex] = rowData;

}
```

Need help on this.
Thank you

Comment: Do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no errors on the console.

Comment: Are you sure that `rowData` is not undefined and immutable?

Comment: Not sure if it is a copy paste issue but shouldn't `onchange=handleUnitPriceChange}` be written as `onchange={handleUnitPriceChange}` (Bracket on left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@api configureorderitemlist // passed from parent
```

This indicates that your data is read-only. You can't modify it. The typical way to handle this is to notify the parent that a change needs to be made, which would be done by the parent.

```
this.dispatchEvent(
  new CustomEvent(
    'datachanged',
    { detail: {
      totalAmt, itemIndex }
  )
);
```

Which is then attached to a handler:

```
<c-mycomponent ondatachange={handleDataChange} configureorderitemlist={data}>
```

Which is then updated by the parent:

```
handleDataChange(event) {
  this.data[event.detail.itemIndex].TotalAmount = event.detail.totalAmt;
}
```

You can read more about the intended [Data Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_data_flow) in LWC.

Comment: The issue got resolved following your approach. Thank you for the quick response and the Data Flow link, which helped to clear the concept.